# modify all rows of a group except the last row in a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe

```
data = [['object 1', 'property 1'], ['object 1','property 11'],['object 1','property 111'], ['object 2', 'property 2'], ['object 3', 'property 3'],['object 3','property 33']]    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['label', 'attribuutLabel'])
```

I want for each label (object) to modify all properties by adding a comma to every attribuutLabel (properties) except the last row.
In case of object with only one property no comma is added.

So the output should look like this:

| label | attribuutLabel |
| --- | --- |
| object 1 | property 1, |
| object 1 | property 11, |
| object 1 | property 111 |
| object 2 | property 2 |
| object 3 | property 3, |
| object 3 | property 33 |

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I want to modify some column values to parse it into a json format. When doing so I can keep the function cleaner, otherwise the function for parsing the rest of the string will get complicated with if statements. I'm new to Python so don't know any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was harder than I though!

But thank you for the exercice ;)

Let's do this:

```
#check labels which are present more than one time
lab_count = df.groupby('label')['attribuutLabel'].count().loc[lambda x: x>1]

#considering the result above, select only the labels >1 and add a comma to all the corresponding "property" BUT the last
df1 = df[df['label'].isin(lab_count.index)].groupby('label', group_keys=False)['attribuutLabel'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1]+",")

#replace/update value from original df with the new values from df1 using .iloc[]
df.iloc[df1.index,1] = df1[:]
df
```

| index | label | attribuutLabel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | object 1 | property 1, |
| 1 | object 1 | property 11, |
| 2 | object 1 | property 111 |
| 3 | object 2 | property 2 |
| 4 | object 3 | property 3, |
| 5 | object 3 | property 33 |